# When I run composer install inside CakePHP3 I get extension missing errors

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

When I run `composer install` inside my CakePHP3 project I get next errors:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.2.12 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.12].
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/debug_kit 3.2.9 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.1.0 <4.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.12].
    - Installation request for cakephp/debug_kit 3.2.9 -> satisfiable by cakephp/debug_kit[3.2.9].
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (note disabled packages for PHP5)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Try running `apt-get build-dep libapache2-mod-php5`

Comment: What part of "the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system" is not clear? Install the extension.

Comment: Most cake php5 packages are dropped on ubuntu 16

Comment: How did you install PHP? Ubuntu 16.04's `php-cgi` and `php-cli` packages should include the `mbstring` extension out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message clearly states your environment is missing `mbstring` extension so just install it: `sudo apt install php-mbstring`